# O(1) lock free container

Tags: java, collections, circular-list, lock-free, atomic

This is a lock-free `Container` class. By `Container` I mean it will hold objects for iteration at a later time. To achieve \$O(1)\$ it returns a token from the `put` method which you can then use to remove the object. The token is actually the node in which the object has been placed.

It is instantiated with a fixed size and throws an exception if capacity is exhausted. Internally it uses a ring buffer.

It is not intended as a candidate for the `Collections` toolbox.

Please try to find a way to break it if you can, or point out any areas where you think it might fail under certain situations.

```
/**
 * Container
 * ---------
 *
 * A lock-free container that offers a close-to O(1) add/remove performance.
 *
 */
public class Container<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  // The capacity of the container.
  final int capacity;
  // The list.
  AtomicReference<Node<T>> head = new AtomicReference<Node<T>>();

  // Constructor
  public Container(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    // Construct the list.
    Node<T> h = new Node<T>();
    Node<T> it = h;
    // One created, now add (capacity - 1) more
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
      // Add it.
      it.next = new Node<T>();
      // Step on to it.
      it = it.next;
    }
    // Make it a ring.
    it.next = h;
    // Install it.
    head.set(h);
  }

  // Empty ... NOT thread safe.
  public void clear() {
    Node<T> it = head.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      // Trash the element
      it.element = null;
      // Mark it free.
      it.free.set(true);
      it = it.next;
    }
  }

  // Add a new one.
  public Node<T> add(T element) {
    // Get a free node and attach the element.
    return getFree().attach(element);
  }

  // Find the next free element and mark it not free.
  private Node<T> getFree() {
    Node<T> freeNode = head.get();
    int skipped = 0;
    // Stop when we hit the end of the list
    // ... or we successfully transit a node from free to not-free.
    while (skipped < capacity && !freeNode.free.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
      skipped += 1;
      freeNode = freeNode.next;
    }
    if (skipped < capacity) {
      // Put the head as next.
      // Doesn't matter if it fails. That would just mean someone else was doing the same.
      head.set(freeNode.next);
    } else {
      // We hit the end! No more free nodes.
      throw new IllegalStateException("Capacity exhausted.");
    }
    return freeNode;
  }

  // Mark it free.
  public void remove(Node<T> it, T element) {
    // Remove the element first.
    it.detach(element);
    // Mark it as free.
    if (!it.free.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Freeing a freed node.");
    }
  }

  // The Node class. It is static so needs the <T> repeated.
  public static class Node<T> {

    // The element in the node.
    private T element;
    // Are we free?
    private AtomicBoolean free = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    // The next reference in whatever list I am in.
    private Node<T> next;

    // Construct a node of the list
    private Node() {
      // Start empty.
      element = null;
    }

    // Attach the element.
    public Node<T> attach(T element) {
      // Sanity check.
      if (this.element == null) {
        this.element = element;
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is already an element attached.");
      }
      // Useful for chaining.
      return this;
    }

    // Detach the element.
    public Node<T> detach(T element) {
      // Sanity check.
      if (this.element == element) {
        this.element = null;
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Removal of wrong element.");
      }
      // Useful for chaining.
      return this;
    }

    public T get () {
      return element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return element != null ? element.toString() : "null";
    }
  }

  // Provides an iterator across all items in the container.
  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new UsedNodesIterator<T>(this);
  }

  // Iterates across used nodes.
  private static class UsedNodesIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    // Where next to look for the next used node.
    Node<T> it;
    int limit = 0;
    T next = null;

    public UsedNodesIterator(Container<T> c) {
      // Snapshot the head node at this time.
      it = c.head.get();
      limit = c.capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      // Made into a `while` loop to fix issue reported by @Nim
      while (next == null && limit > 0) {
        // Scan to the next non-free node.
        while (limit > 0 && it.free.get() == true) {
          it = it.next;
          // Step down 1.
          limit -= 1;
        }
        if (limit != 0) {
          next = it.element;
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
      T n = null;
      if ( hasNext () ) {
        // Give it to them.
        n = next;
        next = null;
        // Step forward.
        it = it.next;
        limit -= 1;
      } else {
        // Not there!!
        throw new NoSuchElementException ();
      }
      return n;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }
  }

}
```

Having posted this request I now find myself searching aggressively for areas of doubt in the code. Some of those follow but I plan to edit the code and remove these as and when you point me in the right direction.

1. Should `Node<T>.element` be `volatile`? I think perhaps.
2. Should `Node<T>.next` be `volatile`? I think not but I am not sure why.
3. Have I chosen a good method for the iterator? I picked a counter rather than seeing the head for the second time to ensure I am resilient to an increase/decrease in size of the ring. This has the small downside of having slightly less predictability but it guarantees termination and is only a bit strange under high parallelism.

NB: `Container` is not intended to be used between a producer and a consumer. It is designed more for keeping a note of which objects have a particular feature in an iterable way. I use it to keep track of threads in the process of calling `put` on a `BlockingQueue` (which may of course block) so I can interrupt them if the queue needs to close.

Comment: The original post is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11080869/823393).

Comment: The declaration of `stop` variable seems to be missing.

Comment: @blufox - my apologies - it should have read `limit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought about a comment, but too long, several things I can think of:

1. This does not guarantee order, i.e. an item is entered into the next free slot, and if there is a fast producer, the order the consumer sees is not guaranteed. Is this intentional?
2. There is no atomic combined detach/attach operation, this means that for example:
   Thread A: Attach starts, calls `getFree()`, which marks the node as not free (and is switched out before the element reference is set)
   Thread B: is iterating, and hits this node, sees it's not free, so valid node, and returns this, if access to element is done (without a null pointer check), will result in an exception - I guess this is okay(?) Or should you test in your iterator and throw a ConcurrentModification?

I think it's simpler if you maintain an `AtomicReference` in the node to the element and test that rather than a separate boolean and the reference.

**Edit 1:**

Looking at this:

```
  // Doesn't matter if it fails. That would just mean someone else was doing the same.
  head.set(freeNode.next);
```

Is this necessarily correct? If Thread A sets \$n+1\$ as head at the same time as Thread B setting n as head, and B succeeds - is the ring in a consistent state? I guess the no ordering guarantee means that this doesn't matter too much, but it would violate the \$O(1)\$ claim! ;) In fact, I would question the whole \$O(1)\$ claim, this is at best \$O(1)\$ and at worst \$O(n)\$...

Comment: 1. You are correct - no statement has been made about ordering and there are no guarantees in that respect. All that is guaranteed is that anything that is in the `Container` throughout iteration time will be offered to the `Iterator` user. Anything that is added/removed to/from the `Container` during iteration may or may not be presented to the user.

Comment: 2. I see your concern. Very good catch. This scenario could then return false from `hasNext` and thus halt the iteration prematurely. I will fix that. A combined attach/detach would be an interesting detail. Note that the `Node` class is `public` and exposes its `attach` and `detach` methods so it is possible (encouraged) to replace the object without freeing the slot it occupies if that is desired.

Comment: I hold the `AtomicBoolean free` in the `Node` to allow for the above activity (instant `detach/attach`). I will investigate your idea to see how it affects the algorithm.

Comment: 2. (revisited) On further thought, your scenario may result in `null` being returned by the `next` method but will not result in a breach of contract as the iteration will continue because `next` is a `Node` not an element. My mistake. BTW - there is an even wider window for this issue because the element can be removed any time between `hasNext` and `next`.

Comment: 2. (yet again) ... but `next` calls `hasNext` again and thus could end up throwing a `NoSuchElement`. :( I'd better fix that.

Comment: btw - I think the standard practice with Iterator is that you would call `hasNext()` and if this is true, call `next()` to get the element, you should not invoke `hasNext()` within the call to `next()`, `next()` should just return the element.

Comment: Fixed `hasNext` to loop until it finds a valid non-null element or runs out of steam. On `hasNext/next` ... have a look at the documentation on `Iterator` ... there is no guarantee that `hasNext` has been called when `next` is called. It is perfectly reasonable (although unusual) for a user to just keep calling `next` until exception is thrown.

Comment: On your Edit1: This line is a small attempt at optimisation that merely moves `head` to follow the most recent `add` which is often also a free element. In my tests it improved the efficiency significantly. It certainly will not cause the algorithm to fail if the head move fails due to parallel contention. ... I agree that O(1..n) would be more accurate but it would take a huge effort to achieve a test case that is O(n). I have found that even under maximum stress I cannot get it above O(1.1)ish.

Answer (score 0):

If thread A does `Container.remove()` and then gets interrupted by thread B after the `.detach()` but before the `//Mark it free`, and thread B then iterates, it's going to get a ref to an item that's `null`, which is probably Not What You Want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - That was the case in the original code but a recent change triggered by a similar scenario pointed out by @Nim means that the iterator will never return a `null` value. In your case the null value will be skipped.